# Age of Empires Online Advisor Hall quest

Tags: age-of-empires-online

I'm level 7 and I have two advisors just sitting in my inventory. They say they require an Advisor Hall. When do I receive said hall or how do I receive it? I am using the civilization Celtics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I'm just impatient since I completed at couple more quests at got to level 8 where I received the quest "I'd like an advisor with that Hall" and was able to build one.

I looked it up on the Wiki and for some reason it says that only the Persians and Greeks are able to build an Advisor Hall, this I have proven to be untrue.

Comment: I am one of the more prolific contributors (http://ageofempiresonline.wikia.com/wiki/User:Jamesjiao) on the age of empires online wiki. I can safely tell you that there is still a lot of work to be done on the site, including the page you mentioned. The advisor hall is available to all civs provided you have finished the pertinent quest line (excluding Persians as they start on level 20). Bottom line, we need more contributors and quality edits.

Comment: @JamesJiao i do you become a contributor for these wikias ive always wanted to help but never really knew how to get started.

Comment: Just create a login and start contributing. Experience with other wiki/wikia sites help, but not essential. In the beginning, I tend to look at how the existing pages are formatted and go from there.